# Is there a version of shareIn() that uses the current coroutine scope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to convert the following Rxjava code to Kt flows:

```
fun fetchData(){
    val net = Observable.fromCallable {
            expensiveNetworkCall()
          }
          .share()
    
    val computeFlow0= net.map{ compute0(it) }
    val computeFlow = net.map{ compute(it) }
    return Observable.merge(computeFlow0, computeFlow)
}
```

I see that Kotlin has [`shareIn()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) which is basically the same as Rxjava's `share()`, but it needs a CoroutineScope.
I could add a parameter to `fetchData(CoroutineScope)` to mirror `shareIn()`, but is there a better way to do this? Is there a version of shareIn() that assumes the same CoroutineScope as the original Flow?

Comment: Why not simply make it a `suspend fun` with `async` for the two computations?

Comment: @GeorgeLeung But if I use `async` would I still be able to return a `Flow`?

Comment: Doing it that way, it wouldn't be able to emit the items into the flow until both were retrieved. But it would look something like `val net = expensiveNetworkCall(); return coroutineScope { listOf(async { compute0(net) }, async { compute(net) }).awaitAll().asFlow() }`. In my opinion, a function that returns a flow should avoid suspending if at all possible. We often want to retrieve a flow in a non-coroutine context, like if we're wanting to use `shareIn` on it in a property initializer.

Comment: Good point, my intuition says `expensiveNetworkCall()` should not be a `Flow`, but an intermediate step in a suspend function. Turns out "that suspend function" is the lambda passed to `flow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your last question: Plain cold Flows and MutableSharedFlows do not have CoroutineScopes, so there would be nothing to access. And SharedFlows that are not MutableSharedFlows don't provide any way to access the scope they are running in.

I don't know Rx beyond browsing its documentation, but I think this is how you could build the equivalent in Kotlin without using a CoroutineScope parameter. Use a `flow` builder to create a suspending context for emitting the items. This will ultimately produce a cold flow that uses the scope of whatever collects it. The code in the lambda will be run each time a collector starts collecting this cold flow.

```
fun fetchData() = flow {
    val net = expensiveNetworkCall() // wrap in withContext if fun blocks
    val computeFlow0 = flow { emit(compute0(net)) }
    val computeFlow = flow { emit(compute(net)) }
    emitAll(merge(computeFlow0, computeFlow))
}
```

Alternatively, I think you could build it using `channelFlow` a little more simply without creating flows to merge. `channelFlow`'s lambda receiver is a CoroutineScope, so you can launch child coroutines inside it to emit the items. Inside a `channelFlow`, you emit items to the resulting flow by using `send()`.

```
fun fetchData() = channelFlow {
    val net = expensiveNetworkCall() // wrap in withContext if fun blocks
    launch { send(compute0(net)) }
    launch { send(compute(net)) } // launch { } is optional on this line
}
```

Supposing you had not just a single expensive call to make, but a whole expensive flow of stuff:

```
fun fetchData() = channelFlow {
    someColdFlow().collect {
        launch { send(compute0(it)) }
        launch { send(compute(it)) } // launch { } is optional on this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing me to `channelFlow`. I implemented `channelFlow` and got the exact behavior I wanted. I also didn't know that `flows` can nest. Great answer!

Comment: That code doesn't make sense, because you're declaring the cold flow and doing nothing with it. The `it` inside your `launch`es wouldn't exist.